# Python elegant way to map string structure

Tags: python, regex, string, string-matching

Let's say I know beforehand that the string

`"key1:key2[]:key3[]:key4"` should map to `"newKey1[]:newKey2[]:newKey3"`

then given `"key1:key2[2]:key3[3]:key4"`,

my method should return `"newKey1[2]:newKey2[3]:newKey3"`

(the order of numbers within the square brackets should stay, like in the above example)

My solution looks like this:

```
predefined_mapping = {"key1:key2[]:key3[]:key4": "newKey1[]:newKey2[]:newKey3"}


def transform(parent_key, parent_key_with_index):
    indexes_in_parent_key = re.findall(r'\[(.*?)\]', parent_key_with_index)

    target_list = predefined_mapping[parent_key].split(":")
    t = []
    i = 0
    for elem in target_list:
        try:
            sub_result = re.subn(r'\[(.*?)\]', '[{}]'.format(indexes_in_parent_key[i]), elem)
            if sub_result[1] > 0:
                i += 1
            new_elem = sub_result[0]
        except IndexError as e:
            new_elem = elem
        t.append(new_elem)
    print ":".join(t)


transform("key1:key2[]:key3[]:key4", "key1:key2[2]:key3[3]:key4")
```

prints `newKey1[2]:newKey2[3]:newKey3` as the result.

Can someone suggest a better and elegant solution (around the usage of regex especially)?

Thanks!

Comment: The elegant solution is to use some standardized notation when addressing dictionary/list paths as I've suggested yesterday. Or to not do this at all - whatever the actual problem is, I'm willing to bet there is a better way to address it than willy-nilly data re-map.

Comment: @zwer that was a typo. Please see the corrected question.

Comment: @zwer  I am using a consistent notation now and deriving a new one out of the input dict. Next step, I decode the new notation and populate a new dict. You suggested to use an open source descriptive language, but I would prefer to roll out my own version. I have made it clear in the other question.

Comment: @ whoever downvoted, please cite the reason. I shall be more than happy to try and clear the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a bit more elegantly by simply splitting the mapped structure on `[]`, then interspersing the indexes from the *actual* data and, finally, joining everything together:

```
import itertools

# split the map immediately on [] so that you don't have to split each time on transform
predefined_mapping = {"key1:key2[]:key3[]:key4": "newKey1[]:newKey2[]:newKey3".split("[]")}

def transform(key, source):
    mapping = predefined_mapping.get(key, None)
    if not mapping:  # no mapping for this key found, return unaltered
        return source
    indexes = re.findall(r'\[.*?\]', source)  # get individual indexes
    return "".join(i for e in itertools.izip_longest(mapping, indexes) for i in e if i)

print(transform("key1:key2[]:key3[]:key4", "key1:key2[2]:key3[3]:key4"))
# newKey1[2]:newKey2[3]:newKey3
```

NOTE: On Python 3 use `itertools.zip_longest()` instead.

I still think you're over-engineering this and that there is probably a much more elegant and far less error-prone approach to the whole problem. I'd advise stepping back and looking at the bigger picture instead of hammering out this particular solution just because it seems to be addressing the immediate need.